# External Javascript not called in HTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a basic chrome extension and need to load an external .js file from my html which doesn't seem to work…

popup.js file

```
'use strict';

window.onload = load() {
    alert("WORKS?")
    var button = document.getElementById("test");
    button.onclick = handler() { 
       alert("helo");
       document.getElementById("hello").textContent="dujn";
    }
}
```

popup.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id='hello'> Change </span>
        <input type="button" value="press" id="test"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function declarations are missing the `function` keyword.

Comment: Replace 'button.onclick = handler() {' with 'button.onclick = function() {'

Comment: thank you, I had completely forgotten about the keywords!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing function keyword from window.onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // rest of your code
}
```

Or

```
window.onload = function load() {
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: thank you, I had completely forgotten about the keywords!

Answer (score 0):

As @Pointy mentioned you will have to create functions using the 'function' keyword

an example would be:

```
function functionName(){
    //code goes here..
}
```

for your example it is the load() function on where you're missing the function keyword

and also on your onclick event you're missing the function keyword at the handler() function

> instead of **load()** -> use **function()** or **function load()**
>
> as well as **handler()** -> use **function()** or **function handler()**